# Why does Light GBM model produce different results while testing?

Tags: machine-learning, training, grid-search, lightgbm, gbm

Using the Light GBM regressor, I have trained my data and, using Grid Search, I got the best parameters, but while testing with the best parameters I am getting different results each time, which means the model produces different results for each test iteration.

I ran the lightgbm twice with the same parameters, but got different results in validation. I found the only random seed parameter to be baggingSeed. After fixing baggingSeed, the problem also occurred. Should I fix any other parameters?

Comment: There are a number of "seed" parameters available, but these are all set by default to fixed integers.  Perhaps try `deterministic=True`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it currently has an issue with data leakage in the cross validation function: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4319

Comment: While this is an important note, I do not see how it relates to the question.